# Figures not appearing in preview pane

Tags: eps, gummi

I am using gummi 0.6.5 and the preview pane does not show eps files

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\hsize]{./fig1.eps}
\caption{sds}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Build log is ok (no errors) but the figure does not show in the preview pane.

Compilation steps are Tex - Dvi- PS- PDF

Comment: Actually the command line shows: dvips: Could not find figure file ./fig1.eps; continuing.
but fig1.eps file is in the same directory of the latex file

Comment: Did you try without `./`? (That actually shouldn’t make a difference, but who knows.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Gummi 0.6.3. I deleted `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` from your code and inserted `\usepackage{epsfig}` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\hsize]{./fig.eps}
\caption{sds}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

% Also you can use \epsfig command instead of \includegraphics

\begin{figure}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig.eps, height=1in, width=1in}
\caption{sds}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```